# Usercontrols XAML c# visual studio 11 windows developer preview

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, windows-8, blend, microsoft-metro

I would like to create my own User controls and insert them into **XAML**,

I saw that it was possible to create in blend.

But When I open my project **C#** on blend 5 I've an error :

> "The project **XXX.csproj** could not be opened. The target framework is
>   not supported."

I read that  **Blend 5** support only **HTML** for now.

How else can I create my own user controls with out blend ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Blend 5 Beta now supports Metro XAML projects but the Dev Preview version did not. If you are still using the old version you should install the Visual Studio 11 Beta that was released last week which includes Blend 5 Beta: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us